# php header("Location") usage at end of script

Tags: php

I am writing an application that submits html forms to a php script. At the end of the php script I have `header("Location: finished.html");`.

The goal is that once all of the data has been analyzed /submitted to sql etc.. the page would redirect.

My question is is this okay practice? It seems unreliable to simply set the header at the end of the script being that various errors could happen throughout the script.

I don't want the page to simply end up at the php script, and I would like to know if there are errors throughout. I am doing as much error checking as I can.

Comment: I don't see any problem with redirecting at the end. You can still check for errors before redirecting and do something else instead.

Comment: What you've described is normal -- It's fairly standard practice for a PHP script to do some processing and then redirect to a static page at the end. If errors occur then the redirect may not happen, but that's also fairly normal; you wouldn't necessarily want to go to a page that says "it's all finished ok", when actually it didn't finish.

Comment: As the others said, as long as you check for errors before redirecting and then only redirect to the desired page if no errors were found. If you don't do that the only issue is that it may be difficult to uncover where the errors are coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `header()` without problems as long as you did not send any response to the client using `echo/print` and the likes or normal text/html, beware of spaces/newlines before `<?php`

PHP stops processing once it encounters an error.

PHP will continue processing if it encounters a warning/notice, but if the onscreen error reporting is enabled, the warning generated output will prevent `header()` from executing as stated by @Simba in the comment.

Comment: I have no echoes or anything of that nature. If there are errors in the php will the header() line still execute?

Comment: If PHP throws an error and stops running, then no, anything after the error will not be executed. If it throws a *warning* and continues running, then the `header()` will still run, but will fail if the warning generated output (ie if the warning message was displayed to the screen).